# xrandr --scale not working with DisplayLink

Tags: linux, xorg, xrandr, displaylink

xrandr's --scale option doesn't work for me on my DisplayLink display. The screen flickers off and back on, but the scale does not change. Can anyone else confirm/deny this issue with their own hardware? Presumably this would be a bug with the DisplayLink driver? I have a Kensington SD3000v.

```
$ uname -r
4.7.0-1-ARCH

$ xrandr --version
xrandr program version       1.5.0
Server reports RandR version 1.5

$ yaourt -Q xorg-server
extra/xorg-server 1.18.4-1 (xorg)

$ yaourt -Q displaylink 
local/displaylink 1.1.62-2

$ lspci | grep V
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev ff)

$ xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x49 cap: 0xb, Source Output, Sink Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 1 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x149 cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 1 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting

$ xrandr --current | grep ^[^\ ]
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 3240, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 3840x2160+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 350mm x 190mm
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 connected 1728x216+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 475mm x 267mm
```

Answer (score 0):

Other users have subsequently confirmed this issue (and voted for it) at [this Display Link Feature Suggestion](https://support.displaylink.com/forums/287786-displaylink-feature-suggestions/suggestions/16077313-fix-linux-driver-scaling?email_login_token=37fe460cdee10aeec04ab01737055740&tracking_code=fb0e2518ee8f085853eebe6cab05558d).